# How to identify the voice in command trigger

Tags: voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I tried the Android demo of CMU Sphinx. It went well, but it also triggers when any other person speaks "Oh might computer".

So, I want to make something like Ok Google which only activates when I speak "Oh mighty Computer" like Ok Google does?

Is there any way to do it on CMU Sphinx?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported. You have to implement voice identification yourself.